# Absolute positioning iPad Stretch across screen

Tags: html, css, ipad, absolute

I am trying to make a header for my webpage stretch across the screen, at the same time it has to slightly overlay the element beneath it.
I am using position:absolute for this task, and its working as a charm in all browsers, except on the iPad.

The style looks like this

```
#headerElement {
 left:0px;
 right:0px;
 top:0px;
 height:100px;
}
```

The problem is, that on the iPad, it only stretches like 75% of the screen (Even though i have added the viewport metatag)

Does any of you have any idea/clue how to fix this?

best regards.
Jonas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this question as it has been fixed.

The problem was a div which had a fixed width, when going iPad, the width went outside the viewport and therefor manipulated the device width.

Fixed by going responsive 100% wrappers when working with lower width devices.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given the header a width?  `width:100%;`

Comment: If i set the width to 100%, and remove the viewport meta, the header goes to approx 90% width of the page. With the viewport meta, no changes at all.

Comment: The funny stuff is, that i have a div without absolute positioning as a footer, outside all wrappers with a width:100%; which does not stretch across the screen neither. Also just around the 90%